# Program to compute n-th number that doesn't contain given digit

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm being requested to write a C++ program that computes the *n-th* number that **doesn't** contain a given digit and the time execution to be lower than 0.1 seconds. Memory doesn't seem to be an issue, as I'm allowed the use of up to 64 MB.

The original text of the problem goes like this:

**[Cifra4](https://infoarena.ro/problema/cifra4)**

> To `represent numbers`, it was decided not to use the digit `C`
>   again.
>   Thus, from the array of natural numbers, all numbers containing the
>   digit `C` will be erased. Let the new array be **S**.
>
> ***Requirements***
>
> **1)** Determine the `N-th` number in **S**.
>
> **2)** `Y` and `Z` are two natural
>   numbers from the array of **all natural numbers**. Determine the number of
>   natural numbers removed from `Y` to `Z`.
>
> ***Input data***
>
> The input file `cifra4.in` contains the first number `T` representing the
>   type of requirement. If `T == 1`, the second row will contain
>   the digit `C` and the number `N`. If `T == 2`, the
>   second line will contain the digit `C` and two natural numbers `Y`and
>   `Z`.
>
> ***Output data***
>
> In the output file `cifra4.out` will contain in the first row
>   one natural number according to the type of requirement.
>
> ***Restrictions and clarifications***
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 10 ^ 13
> 0 ≤ C ≤ 9
> 1 ≤ Y ≤ 10 ^ 13
> 1 ≤ Z ≤ 10 ^ 13
> for 20% of the tests, N will have a maximum of 5 digits
> for 20% of the tests, Y and Z will have a maximum of 6 digits
> ```
>
> ***Example 1***
>
> **cifra4.in**
>
> ```
> 1
> 0 11
> ```
>
> **cifra4.out**
>
> ```
> 12
> ```
>
> ***Example 2***
>
> **cifra4.in**
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 3 20
> ```
>
> **cifra4.out**
>
> `10`

My best try was a code that determined (or at least was supposed to) the n-th number that doesn't contain the digit "0", but for `10 ^ 13` it returned `23210987654321`, which obviously contains `0`.

My slower, but correct approach was what I ended up keeping. Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream in("cifra4.in");
std::ofstream out("cifra4.out");

const long long pow_of_10[14] = {0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000,
                                 10000000000, 100000000000, 1000000000000};

void req_1 ()
{
    short digit;
    long long n;
    in >> digit >> n;
    for (long long i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        long long nr = i;
        if (nr)
        {
            long k = 1;
            do
            {
                if (nr % 10 == digit)
                {
                    n += pow_of_10[k];
                    i += pow_of_10[k] - 1;
                    break;
                }
                nr /= 10;
                k++;
            }
            while (nr);
        }
        else if (digit == 0) n++;
    }
    out << n - 1;
}

void req_2()
{
    short digit;
    long long lhs, rhs;
    long long elim = 0;
    in >> digit >> lhs >> rhs;
    for (long long i = lhs; i <= rhs; i++)
    {
        long long nr = i;
        while (nr)
        {
            if (nr % 10 == digit)
            {
                elim++;
                break;
            }
            nr /= 10;
        }
    }
    out << elim;
}

int main()
{
    short requirement;
    in >> requirement;
    if (requirement == 1)
        req_1();
    else
        req_2();
}
```

***NOTE***

I'm not asking for code necesarily, but for ideas, possible algorithms that can execute up to 10 ^ 13 in decent time, preferably the time requested by the problem, but 1 second will do fine for me.

Comment: You must make your question much more focused for it to get meaningful answers.

Comment: @einpoklum I think mentioning what you dislike is more helpful for newcomers than just disliking the post and rendering it, basically, unillegible for an answer, regardless if the newcomer edits it anymore or not.

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Try reading StackOverflow's [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What I dislike is, generally speaking, the opposite of that...

Comment: @einpoklum Well, I included all the info I have, my grammar wasn't bad and the title was very representative of what my question was. Or give me more details of what you think is "bad practice" for questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine that `9` is the forbidden digit. In this case you can just convert your number to base-9 and you're done.

Now, what happens when the forbidden digit is different, say `d`? It's still a base-9 number but you have to map your digits, such that digits below `d` remain unaffected, and `d` and above are mapped to the digit `d + 1`.

For example, when the forbidden digit is `7` and `n` is `125`.

- Step 1: convert to base-9: 125<sub>10</sub> = 148<sub>9</sub>
- Step 2: map the digits. 1 → 1, 4 → 4, 8 → 9

The solution is 149.

Answer (score 0):

Since the decimal digits of a number are "independent" of each other, in that setting one digit does not affect any other digits - once you've fixed a prefix of (at least one) more-significant digits, leaving n' less-significant digits, you know you have exactly (10 - 1)^n' = 9^n' numbers with that prefix and no forbidden digits in the unfixed part. For example, for 3-digit numbers beginning with 1, there are exactaly 81 numbers with no 0 in them.

The only 'snag' here is that setting the most-significant digit to zero means that you get the same number for different numbers of digits (012, 0012 etc.). But you should be able to work around this issue as well - by determining how many digits you're going to need for the n'th number without your forbidden digit. Very similar to the argument I described above. Then you know you have 10-1 = 9 options there if your forbidden digit is 0 or 10-2 = 8 otherwise.